# How to put jars in the same folder with the Maven Assembly Plugin

Tags: java, maven, maven-assembly-plugin

I have a multi-module Apache Maven 3.3.3 project with n*** (multiple) module projects:

```
/mvnModular
           /modules
           /modules /mainApp    /pom.xml
           /modules /module1    /pom.xml
           /modules /module2    /pom.xml
           /modules /moduleChat /pom.xml
           /modules /moduleBlog /pom.xml
```

...

**modules** has only one file, pom.xml:

```
<groupId>mainmod.modules</groupId>
<artifactId>modules</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>pom</packaging>

<modules>
  <module>..\mainApp\pom.xml</module>
  <module>..\module1\pom.xml</module>
  <module>..\module2\pom.xml</module>
  <module>..\moduleChat\pom.xml</module>
  <module>..\moduleBlog\pom.xml</module>
</modules>
```

...

How can I go about adding all the .jar files from the individual modules projects into a folder, called lib, in the project root folder, mvnModular?

**This is what I would like at the end:**

```
/mvnModular
    mainApp.jar
                /lib
                /lib    /module1.jar
                /lib    /module2.jar
                /lib    /moduleChat.jar
                /lib    /moduleBlog.jar
```

.....

The individual modules have a **pom.xml** file like this one:

```
<parent>
  <groupId>mainmod.modules</groupId>
  <artifactId>modules</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <relativePath>../modules/pom.xml</relativePath>
</parent>

<groupId>mainmod.modules.module2</groupId>
<artifactId>module2</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>module1</name>
```

---

**UPDATE**

The idea is to have an application written in a way that a user will download the project `mainApp` that contains mainApp.jar in the root mvnModular folder innitially, which is the main project. Then the application (mainApp.jar) could be extended by adding modules to a folder called packages in the mvnModular root.

Answer (score 2):

You can use **maven-antrun-plugin** for that. This will have to be added to every module.

Check the sample below.

parent POM

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>TestMavenModules</groupId>
    <artifactId>TestMavenModules</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <modules>
        <module>Module1</module>
        <module>Module2</module>
    </modules>

</project>
```

Module1 POM

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>TestMavenModules</groupId>
        <artifactId>TestMavenModules</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <artifactId>Module</artifactId>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.7</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <target>
                                <copy
                                    file="${project.build.directory}/${project.artifactId}-${project.version}.jar"
                                    todir="../PackagedJars" />
                            </target>
                        </configuration>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>run</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Module2 POM

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>TestMavenModules</groupId>
        <artifactId>TestMavenModules</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <artifactId>Module2</artifactId>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.7</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <target>
                                <copy
                                    file="${project.build.directory}/${project.artifactId}-${project.version}.jar"
                                    todir="../PackagedJars" />
                            </target>
                        </configuration>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>run</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Finally you'll have jars in PackagedJars directory in the root.

```
/PackagedJars
----/Module1-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
----/Module2-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```